# Find the range of $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x^2-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

While finding the range of $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$, we are able to find the range as $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Is there any possibility of $f(x)$ being negative?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is always positive $\forall\lvert x\rvert\gt 1, x \in \mathbb R$ (the domain of the function), $\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2-1}}\gt 0\forall x\in\mathscr D_f$ will . Also, the range of this function is $\mathbb R^+$ and not $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

There is not. If it were the case, then $\sqrt{x^2 - 1} < 0$ as a result. However, $\sqrt x \ge 0$ by definition, so $f$ has a range of $\Bbb R^+ = \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid x > 0 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$, let $x=\sec t$
Hence,
$$f(\sec t)= \frac{1}{\lvert\tan t\rvert}\leftarrow\sqrt{k^2}=\lvert k\rvert\implies f(\sec t)=\lvert\cot t\rvert\implies\mathscr R_f=\mathbb R^+$$